# React: Passing Props not working. Am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

as you may get from the title, passing props in react is not working. And i don´t get why.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';


const Login = (props) => {
    return<div>Login</div>

}

export default Login;
```

On my App.js page here is the following:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/Login.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" >
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Problem**: if i start the script and render the page, nothing is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see any props passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass `<Login />` as the element. Try this code:
App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/Login.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Login />`... the `Login` component isn't passed any props so I wouldn't expect to see any in the component. Your issue is a misunderstanding how the `Route` component works. The only valid children of the `Route` component is another `Route` component in the case of nesting routes, otherwise, the routed content is passed on the `Route` component's `element` prop as a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null;
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

The `Login` component should be passed to the `element` prop.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more details/explanation see [Why does `<Route>` have an `element` prop instead of `render` or `component`?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#why-does-route-have-an-element-prop-instead-of-render-or-component)